# Stop MVC app from requesting a specific kquery (jquery-1.7.2) which does not exist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundler

My ASP MVC page keeps requesting /scripts/jquery-1.7.2, but only when I click "back" in certain pages. I have no idea why. That file does not exist, so I get "jquery is not defined" errors.

- I've uninstalled everything related to JQuery from Nuget
- I've done a Windows file search for all files containing the text, "jquery-1.7*". Only comments in certain JS libraries contain the text.
- I've deleted every old JQuery-related file
- I've cleaned the project and deleted the ~/obj/ and ~/bin/ directories within.
- I've removed any mention from my BundleConfig

Actual script files as part of this project:

[image: Actual script files included in project (directory contents are the same)]

My HTML  section (slightly trimmed)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Foo</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <script type="text/javascript">         var myRootDir = '/';</script>

    <!--Problem here: Should not be loading these individual jqueryui files because they aren't in BundleConfig-->
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--Trimmed...-->
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/TableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/TableTools_JUI.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--Problem here: Where is this from?! -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ZeroClipboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/TableTools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/dataTables.editor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
```

My BundleConfig:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
        bundles.Add(
            new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"
            )
        );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dataTables").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables*",
                    "~/Scripts/ZeroClipboard*",
                    "~/Scripts/TableTools.*",
                    "~/Scripts/dataTables.editor.*"
                    ));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/site.css",
            "~/Content/demo_table_jui.css",
            "~/Content/TableTools.css",
            "~/Content/TableTools_JUI.css"
            ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you cleared browser cache?

Comment: You are sure that the file is missing in html-markup? Try Ctrl+F and look in Project. It is not caching.

Comment: @MacAttack: I did. I also tried accessing with FireFox, which has never been to this page.

Comment: I would then look at the browser dev tools (through f12 or firebug) and see where the request is being made. Looking at the Network tab, you should be able to see how it is being loaded.

Comment: @webdeveloper: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you are asking whether jquery-1.7* exists, no -- it does not. jquery-1.8.1.min.js does exist.

Comment: Ok, you remove it locally from file system, now optimization can't find it. You post head block, as I can see without bundle links (you use debug=true in config). That's why I think it hard coded on one of the pages, maybe in section.

Comment: @MacAttack: The browser debugger says the request is from "/Manage", but it's actually from _Layout.shtml, the base template into which all MVC4 views are inserted. It is the one and only place in the entire project (my code, anyway) that includes JS scripts. It does so from "<head>"
`@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jqueryui")
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTables")
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
`@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac Attack's question, "Have you cleared browser cache?", was sort of right.
The browser cache was the problem, but I had to clear it with CCleaner.
IE's "Safety --> Delete Browsing History (☑ checked everything)" did not work for some reason.
I had even manually killed all IE processes just in case a crashed process was locking certain  files.

I had also tried it in Firefox which did the same thing for some reason when I first visited the page, but a "CTRL+F5" worked as it should have in IE and cleared up the problem.

I've +1's Mac Attack's question.

Lesson for today: IE9's cache clear apparently does not work, at least in this case.